# How to pass values for seconds in countdown timer , I am able to pass minutes but not seconds , it always start from 60

Tags: android, timer

Here is my method to start , i am passing minutes from the Textview  , how can i pass user defined seconds to star with

```
   startbtnn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(Integer.parseInt(timertxt11.getText().toString())*60000,1000,v);

                timer.start();
            }
        });
```

and Here s the class that is used

```
       public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer
        {

        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval,View v)
        { super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
//            timertxt.setText("Completed.");
        }

         @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms1 = String.format("%02d",TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)));
            String hms2 = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));


            System.out.println(hms1+": " +hms2);
            timertxt11.setText(hms1);
            timertxt22.setText(hms2);
        }
    }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: are you getting error or what??

Comment: not getting any error , seconds in my timer always starts with 60 and i need to set it user defined when it starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have two TextView(one shows mins and another shows secs)

```
int mins = Integer.parseInt(minTextView.getText().toString());
int secs = Integer.parseInt(secTextView.getText().toString());
long totalMillis = (mins * 60 + secs) * 1000L;
new CounterClass(totalMillis, 1000L, v).start();
```

or if you just want one TextView

```
try {
    // "mm:ss" is just an example. define the input format yourself.
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = format.parse(timeTextView.getText().toString());
    new CounterClass(date.getTime(), 1000, v).start();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // handle exception here
}
```